# converter json to two dimensional array

Tags: jquery, json

My json data:

```
{
   "d":[
      {
         "__type":"DashBoardControl.Info.DashBoardSettingInfo",
         "VisitTime":"183",
         "Browser":"Firefox"
      },
      {
         "__type":"DashBoardControl.Info.DashBoardSettingInfo",
         "VisitTime":"28",
         "Browser":"Chrome"

      },
      {
         "__type":"DashBoardControl.Info.DashBoardSettingInfo",
         "VisitTime":"2",
         "Browser":"IE"
      },
      {
         "__type":"DashBoardControl.Info.DashBoardSettingInfo",
         "VisitTime":"1",
         "Browser":"Opera"
      }
   ]
}
```

I try to make this data in two dimension array like this.But I am fail.

```
                        var BrowserWiseVisit = [];
                        if (msg.d.length > 0) {
                            var arrVisit = [];
                            $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {

                                arrVisit = [];
                                arrVisit.push(item.Browser);
                                arrVisit.push(item.VisitTime);
                                BrowserWiseVisit.push(arrVisit);

                            });


                        }
```

I want a data like this format

```
[['Firefox', 183], ['Chrome', 28], ['IE', 2], ['Opera', 1]];
```

for  use http://www.jqplot.com/ this plugin.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me, http://jsfiddle.net/L5vf9/

Comment: I caught my mistake.I use `arrVisit.push(parseInt(item.VisitTime));` instead of ` arrVisit.push(item.VisitTime);`
 and its work.Thanks for jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems You are doing right for http://www.jqplot.com/

There You want Data
[['Firefox', 183], ['Chrome', 28], ['IE', 2], ['Opera', 1]];

Simply In your js parse  the visitTime data to int.
Here is the Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/HCNL5/

```
var BrowserWiseVisit = [];
                        if (msg.d.length > 0) {
                            var arrVisit = [];
                            $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {

                                arrVisit = [];
                                arrVisit.push(item.Browser);
                                arrVisit.push(parseInt(item.VisitTime));
                                BrowserWiseVisit.push(arrVisit);

                            });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var BrowserWiseVisit = [];
if (msg.d.length > 0) {
   var arrVisit = [];
   $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {
      arrVisit = [item.Browser,item.VisitTime];
      BrowserWiseVisit.push(arrVisit);
   });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do:

```
var sampleData = [], results = d;
for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++) {
    var result = results[i];
    sampleData.push({ browser: result.Browser, visitTime: result.VisitTime});
}
```

Comment: He wants a two dimensional array.

Comment: okay, perhaps he could use this as a starting point. Don't understand if it needed a downvote