# from JSON to 2D array

Tags: java, json

I have json and i want to store them 2D array.

This is my json

```
[  
   {  
      "IsStudent":true,
      "Name":"Ali",
      "age":16,
      "ID":1
   },
   {  
      "IsStudent":false,
      "Name":"Emad",
      "age":17,
      "ID":2
   }
]
```

so I want to store all the information to 2D array :

array[0][0] = true

array[0][1] = Ali

array[0][2] = 16

array[0][3] = 1

and so on..

I tried alot to get those values by using split and join but it doesn't work for me

```
JSONArray jarr2 = new JSONArray("my json is here");
String[] resultingArray = jarr.join("\":").split(",\"");
System.out.println(resultingArray[3]);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793931/converter-json-to-two-dimensional-array

Comment: Arrays have one type and you are adding boolean, string, integers in same array. Make a class, create variables of same type as in json and parse your json by using this class as model. or just treat each value as string i.e. "true","Ali","16","1".

Comment: no problem i want to store them as string.

Comment: Don't do that. Create a class having that parameters as fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Read json file example**:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader("/test.json");
            JsonParser jsonParser =  new JsonParser();
            JsonArray array = (JsonArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);
            searchJsonElemnet(array);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void searchJsonElemnet(JsonArray jsonArray){
        String[][] matrix = new String[2][4];
        int i =0;
        int j = 0;
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : jsonArray) {
             for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
                 matrix[i][j] = entry.getValue().toString();
                 j++;
            }
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
        for (String[] row : matrix)
        {
            for (String value : row)
            {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Output :**

*true
"Ali"
16
1
false
"Emad"
17
2*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library `org.json` and do something like this:

```
String jsonData = "[{\"IsStudent\":true,\"Name\":\"Ali\",\"age\":16,\"ID\":1},{\"IsStudent\":false,\"Name\":\"Emad\",\"age\":17,\"ID\":2}]";

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    boolean isStudent = jsonObject.getBoolean("isStudent");
    String name = jsonObject.getString("Name");
    int age = jsonObject.getInt("age");
    int id = jsonObject.getInt("ID");

    //You can do the other stuf that you want with the fetched data.
}
```