# Convert JSON response into 2D String Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

Hello i´m new in Android and searching the whole morning for a solution.
I have only found posts which could not help me. The interessting post  [from JSON to 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536159/from-json-to-2d-array) dont worked in my project. I tried on different ways to implement this method into my code.
I just want to convert my JSON response into a 2D String Array like this format:

Array[0][0] = Artikelnummer;

Array[0][1] = Preis;

Array[0][2] = Von;

Array[0][3] = Bis;

Array[0][4] = art_link;

Array[1][0] = Artikelnummer;

Array[1][1] = Preis;

Array[1][2] = Von;

Array[1][3] = Bis;

Array[0][4] = art_link;

.....

...

..

**The JSON response looks like:**

```
[{
"Artikelnummer": 01578675,
"Preis": 3.27,
"Von": "2017-10-16 08:00:00",
"Bis": "2017-10-20 13:00:00",
"art_link": "http://link/.jpg"
},
{
"Artikelnummer": 99999999,
"Preis": 9.99,
"Von": "2017-10-16 08:00:00",
"Bis": "2017-10-20 13:00:00",
"art_link": "http://link/.jpg"
},
{
"Artikelnummer": 55555555,
"Preis": 5.55,
"Von": "2017-10-16 08:00:00",
"Bis": "2017-10-20 13:00:00",
"art_link": "http://link/.jpg"
 },
{
"Artikelnummer": 88888888,
"Preis": 8.88,
"Von": "2017-10-16 08:00:00",
"Bis": "2017-10-20 13:00:00",
"art_link": "http://link/.jpg"
}]
```

**I get my response on this way:**

```
         URL url = new URL("https://myjson.com");
         HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) 
         url.openConnection();

         InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(inputStream));
         String line = "";

         while(line != null){
              line = bufferedReader.readLine();
              data = data + line;

         ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
         JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);

         for(int i =0 ;i <jArray.length(); i++){
             listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));
             JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject) jArray.get(i);
        }
```

**But how I can convert my jArray response into a String[][]**

Something like this, but this didn´t work for my project

```
String[][] matrix = new String[jArray.length][5];
```

Comment: when should second row be started for 2 day array?

Comment: please add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse your JSON string into a `JSONArray`, then iterate over it and populate a given row in a 2D array of strings.

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
String[][] array = new String[json.length()][5];

for (int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {                           
    JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
    array[i][0] = String.valueOf(obj.getInt("Artikelnummer"));
    array[i][1] = String.valueOf(obj.getDouble("Preis"));
    array[i][2] = obj.getString("Von");
    array[i][3] = obj.getString("Bis");
    array[i][4] = obj.getString("art_link");
}
```